# Prudent to Apply for Same Position/Different Departments at Same Company?

Tags: applications, human-resources

Basically within the *same* company there are two positions:

```
Coordinator in department X
Coordinator in department Y
```

Same position w/ the same exact duties, different department. Is there any adverse effect to applying for both concurrently?

Comment: @JaneS Not sure this is a duplicate. The key difference here is that the company posted two positions that are exactly the same, just in different departments. Depending on the industry OP is in, it could be that the choice of department won't have a substantial impact on his work or career track. Now, the answers on the linked question kind of work for this OP but that's mainly because they don't even mention the problem of appearing to mass-apply when you're talking very different positions.

Comment: @Lilienthal Sorry, the answers for that other question do indeed fit this question.  There are two roles (it doesn't matter if they are functionally the same), the OP simply wants to know if applying for both will impact on their chances of either or both, which is the essence of the other question.

Comment: @JaneS Yes, the answers do but for a duplicate the *question* should be the same and I'd argue that it's different. The linked question could be about a job as a Marketing Director and one as an IT manager whereas this question could be about an Office Manager for the Sales or Purchasing department. Applying for both is foolish in the first scenario but fine in the second. The problem is that the 2 answers on the linked question don't address that issue at all. Ironically Martin actually *does* mention this in his answer here.

Comment: In short, the answers here should probably boil down to "Go ahead and apply for both" while on the linked questions answers should be "Probably not, unless the positions are almost exactly the same [with a pointer to this question]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question with no straightforward answer.
I have worked in companies where the view on that would be by applying for both you are showing a lack of focus on where you want to be and are wishy-washy.  Other companies have no problem with you applying for both...some will even forward the resume/application so that both areas have the opportunity to see it.

If possible you should try and speak with either an HR person at the company or, if possible, with the hiring managers.  This may allow you not only to figure out whether it's acceptable to apply for both but it may give you insight into whether both positions are identical in reality.  It may be that you end up being interested in one more than the other and decide that is the only one you want to apply for.

If you are applying internally you could ask people you work with (even your current Mgr if they are OK with their people moving around/up) or HR and see what how the culture views this.  Often times it is simply a personal opinion and not an accepted practice.  I have seen a Director reject a resume for a college intern because she put down reading as a hobby.  His view was that reading is a solitary activity and therefore they likely wouldn't be a good 'team player'.  He was a good Director, that was his personal view but he made the final decision.

Comment: Welcome to the site Martin, thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: +1 the best thing to do is call the company and express your interest in both positions and ask how they want you to apply.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any adverse effect to applying for both concurrently?

No there isn't, if the specific workplace doesn't want you applying for both, they will likely inform you. But otherwise it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the company is large enough the HR chain, the hiring manager, and the people involved in the interview will be completely different.

Even if they are both being advertised at the same time, they could be on completely different schedules for filling their position. One could fill it in a week, the other could take 3 months.

The different departments could have slightly different work locations, which could mean that the pool of candidates for what seem to be identical jobs could have few overlaps.

If one department makes you an offer, they will ask that you remove yourself from consideration for other job in the company. They don't want to be bidding against themselves.

For many companies  it is far easier to apply for the 2nd, 3rd or 4th opening because you have already completed the hard parts of uploading the information from your resume into their overly complex application webpage. This ease of being able to apply to multiple positions encourages you to do so.